# How To Extract URLs From a Hindi Newspaper Amar Ujala

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract the url of articles present on a Hindi Newspaper called Amar Ujala.
Link: https://www.amarujala.com/india-news?src=mainmenu

In 'Network' section of Dev Tools, It seems required API is 'https://electionresultapi.amarujala.com/get-article-reactions' and under the 'payload' section we have the required URL.
[image]

I tried the following code to fetch the URL

```
import requests
import json

# Assuming you have an API key, replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual API key
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Your_Auth'
}

api_response = requests.post('https://electionresultapi.amarujala.com/get-article-reactions', headers=headers)
print(api_response.status_code)

data = api_response.text
parse_json = json.loads(data)
print(parse_json)
```

But as expected it is giving output from 'Response' section of Dev Tools.
How to extract URL from the [weblink](https://www.amarujala.com/india-news?src=mainmenu) shared above.

Comment: Are you trying to get the articles' URLs or the reactions on the articles?

Comment: @MohitGoyal I am trying to get the articles URLs but I couldn't find the URL of the article anywhere but under the 'payload' of reactions on the articles thus was trying to extract from reaction api if at all possible...may be If we can find suitable api endpoint that would be really great!!

Comment: Instead of going through all this hassle, you can check for sitemaps, if they fulfill your needs. [Sitemap_News](https://www.amarujala.com/sitemap-news-v1.xml) and check [Robots](https://www.amarujala.com/robots.txt) to get thorough details about the website's sitemaps.

Comment: @MohitGoyal, thanks Mohit this is definitely better than my approach. I just tired it and got 700 URLs. What would be your suggest if someone wants to have the URLs of all the articles ever published on a newspaper website...

Comment: There are other sitemaps mentioned in the *robots* file, and some of the sitemaps are even nested, if you traverse through all, that may be all the URLs on the website.

Comment: yeah, just tried that thanks!! this was really helpful

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254231/discussion-between-vinay-sharma-and-mohit-goyal).

Answer (score 0):

What you have figured out so far is partial info.

Vinay so I have analyzed the website a bit. As you may have noticed on left side of the pane, consists of cards that have news in them.

So every card is basically a section that wraps 5 divs in it. We are interested in div with class='image_description'. there you will find an anchor tag that holds the URL you require.

Little more info on what you have figured out-
So the URL stirng I mentioned above is passed to http endpoint you mentioned:
https://electionresultapi.amarujala.com/get-article-reactions and URL string is an input given to the above endpoint with the POST method.

Hope this helps. in case of further queries, happy to help.

Comment: when we extract the hrefs from div with class='image_description' for a given link. we can only extract a limited number of article links. As you would have notices, the list of articles keep on loading dynamically as you scroll down. Thus I was looking for API endpoint from where I can get the complete list of articles link if possible.

Comment: Then the answer is no I guess right? As you mentioned list goes on if we scroll ahead which points to some front-end logic that takes over when you scroll and some event that issues an request that appends more articles on the window. Let me know if this helped and please upvote/accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I am not sure, the answer is 'No' @lib